# Sitemap generation for an angularJS app with separate front and back end

Tags: java, angularjs, seo, sitemap, modular-design

I have an application having separate front and back end. Front end is made in angularJS and backend is in Java.

My application is generating dynamic data quite frequently and I want to introduce SEO to my app, for that I want to create sitemap.

Since my angularJS apps are single page applications. I am facing issue how to create dynamic sitemap which gets updated as soon as a new page/data is added. Like stackoverflow in which sitemap is updated as soon as a new question is added.

One solution I thought is to create a sitemap on the backend and create an api call that returns the sitemap. I create a cron job which calls that api and gets an updated sitemap which I place on my server for google to see the file.

I want to know if my approach is correct and if there any other better approach to my problem. Thank you.